# How passing variable to frameset for muli search

Tags: php, search-engine, frameset

I'm looking solution to make my searches as Google+Bing+Yahoo+ASk
i want using frameset to send query when send query show link as other search engine in top frame named header

i tried to send query and see result in header.php

Resources is there:
index.html

```
<pre>
<frameset>
 rows="30,*" frameborder="0">
<frame name="main" src="search-engine.php" />    
<frame name="header" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no" src="header.php" /> 
<frameset>
```

search-engine.php

```
<form action="header.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="keyword" autocomplete="off"  />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<?php
$keyword=$_GET["keyword"];
echo "<a href='http://www.bing.com/search?q=$keyword' title=''>bing</a>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<a href='http://www.google.com/search?q=$keyword' title=''>google</a>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<a href='http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=$keyword' title=''>Yahoo!</a>";
 ?>
```

header.php

```
header("Location: http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=$keyword");
```

Answer (score 0):

Framesets are 1993. They are bad in usability, because -amongst other problems- they mess with your browser history. I believe they are not even supported in XHTML and HTML5. If you're developing something new here, don't start with frames.

These sites work with Ajax. It means they send a request to the server in the background, while the page is visible. The responsed is processed using Javascript and put inside an element on the page. That way, you can update parts of the page, while the page itself doesn't get refreshed.

Search for `AJAX`, which should lead you to a great number of tutorials about this subject.

Comment: Thank you to help me,can you take sample code written in Ajax, for example serach in multi search engines on one page (user can select witch media type witch engine)?

Comment: There are millions of examples. I gave you the term to look for, please try yourself from here. If you got any specific questions, we can help with those.